# BIND9 cannot resolve external DNS queries

Tags: dns, bind

First of all, I am not experienced in this field. Therefore, the question may be nonsensical.

I have installed BIND9 on my server machine (Ubuntu 16.04). DNS forwarding does not work if the client machine performs external DNS query.

The contents of some files on my server are as follows:

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
acl "trusted"{
    10.5.147.189; #kasirga server-bogurtlen
    10.5.146.142; #host dut
    10.5.147.210; #host jalapeno
    10.5.147.215; #host nar
    10.5.147.120; #ahududu
    10.5.147.72;  #ceviz
    10.5.147.76; #greyfurt
    10.5.147.79;  #havuc
    10.5.147.118; #kestane
    10.5.146.122;  #erik
    10.5.147.206;  #mandalina
    10.5.147.152;  #incir
    10.5.147.180; #ot
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

     forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;        
     };
    recursion yes;
    allow-query {trusted;};
    forward only;

    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.5.147.189
    gateway 10.5.146.1
    netmask 255.255.254.0
    dns-nameservers 10.1.11.103 10.1.12.104
```

The outputs of some commands running on my client "incir" are as follows:

It can successfully obtain the IP address of another client in local network.

```
samet@incir:~$ nslookup mandalina
Server:     10.5.147.189
Address:    10.5.147.189#53

Name:   mandalina.kasirgalabs.home
Address: 10.5.147.206
```

However, it cannot obtain the IP address of "google.com".

```
samet@incir:~$ nslookup google.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 10.5.147.189, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 10.5.147.152
    gateway 10.5.146.1
    netmask 255.255.254.0
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

I could not figure out how to solve this problem. As I said before, I do not have much knowledge. If I am supposed to show the contents of specific files, please tell me and I will do.

Answer (score 0):

In your options section add these:

```
allow-recursion { "trusted"; };
allow-query-cache { "trusted"; };
```

BIND nowadays has very fine grained control over who can query what, and by extension cause the server to do (i.e. to go out and recurse).

https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00503